# Specman - how to convert struct to a list of string

Tags: struct, verification, specman

What is the efficient way to convert struct to a list of strings (list of all its field - name and value)?

For example the following struct:

```
struct spot_top_s {
   %D_LDO_SFS_EN : uint(bits:1);
   %D_COMP3P3_ACC_EN : uint(bits:1);
   %D_BGCOMP_TRIM : uint(bits:6);
   %spot_top_jtagtest_out : bit;
   %spot_top_jtagtest_in  : bit;

}; // spot_top_s
```

Comment: Do you want to be able to do this with any struct? Then you need to use the reflection interface. If only for this struct it's trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed a generic code which accepts any struct can be implemented using reflection.
Here is one example of such a code. You can modify it, for example - add to the list only physical fields (by calling "if it.is_physical()"), etc.

```
extend sys {
    get_fields(input_struct : any_struct) : list of string is {
        var struct_rf : rf_struct;
        struct_rf = rf_manager.get_struct_of_instance( input_struct);

        var struct_fields : list of rf_field;
        struct_fields = struct_rf.get_fields();

        var field_type_rf : rf_type;
        var field_value_unsafe : untyped;

        for each in struct_fields {
            result.add(it.get_name());
            var f:=  it.get_value_unsafe(input_struct);
            field_type_rf = it.get_type();
            field_value_unsafe = it.get_value_unsafe(input_struct);
            result.add(field_type_rf.value_to_string(field_value_unsafe));
        };
    };

    // usage example:
    my_spot_top : spot_top_s;
    post_generate() is also {
        print get_field(my_spot_top);
    };
};
```

Comment: Is there any option to add the bit number of each field?

Comment: for scalar fields - you can get their size.   " if field_type_rf is a rf_scalar (trs) {
                field_size = trs.get_size_in_bits();". search for rf_scalar in specman e reference. if the field is a list - then you have to sum (get the length of the list an * by the size of each field), etc.